# How to extract string field value from a URL using regular expression in shell script?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am working on a project in which I need to make a url call to one of my server from the bash shell script..

```
http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

After hitting the above url, I will be getting the below response which I need to parse it and extract value of `state` from it

```
num_retries_allowed: 3 count: 30 count_behind: 100 state: POST_INIT num_rounds: 60 hour_col: 2 day_col: 0
```

Now I want to extract `state` variable value using regular expressions. I am able to extract `count` and `count_behind` value from it but not sure how to extract `state` value from it.

```
#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for count and count_behind
COUNT=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'count: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
COUNT_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'count_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')

# how to extract state variable value here?
STATE= what do I add here?
```

Also if in `$DATA` if `state` variable is not there by any chance, then I want to assign `0` to `STATE` variable. After that I want to verify the conditionals and exit out of the script depending on that.

If `STATE` is equal to `POST_INIT` then exit successfully out of the shell script or `STATE` is equal to 0, then exit successfully as well.

```
#verify conditionals
if [[ $STATE -eq "POST_INIT" || $STATE -eq "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `grep -P`:

```
state=$(grep -oP 'state: \K\S+' <<< "$DATA")   
[[ -z "$state" ]] && state=0
echo "$state"
POST_INIT
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. How do I assign zero value if state is missing by any chance in the $DATA?

Comment: After `grep` command you can just do: `[[ -z "$state" ]] && state=0`

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, meaning if `state:` string is missing in input. Can you update your answer with this as well so that it is complete?

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Can you explain little bit how this works if `state:` string is missing then how will it assign 0 to it and how will it work in normal case. Just for my understanding purpose.

Comment: If `state: ` is missing in input then grep's output is empty and hence `state` variable is also empty. And `-z "$state"` is check for emptiness of variable. Part after `&&` executed if left hand condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70164/discussion-between-david-and-anubhava).